# JFrame freezes during while loop

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, jframe, jprogressbar

I am working on a Java program, which reads text files does some probability calculations. Reading files and all related calculations are done in a while loop.

I had created a GUI using JFrame, where i had added a Progress bar (using JProgressBar) to show the progress since the program takes a while to process the files.

The code looks like -

```
while( there are more files to read )
{
    Read this file ;
    Do calculations ;

    Update progress bar ;
}
```

Now, the problem is **once the while loop starts and the first file is processed, the JFrame simply freezes**. The progress bar does not get updated and i cannot press any button in the JFrame. Once the while loop ends the frame is updated and the progress bar is updated to its final value **(hence, the progress bar starts from 0 then pauses then finally goes to 100)**.

Could some one explain why is the JFrame freezing ? Is it possible to update it (progress bar in the JFrame) in the while loop iterations ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing your time intense task in the event dispatch thread (EDT). This is a bad idea as the EDT also updates the UI. Therefore if this thread is blocked no update to the UI is done.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `threads`, that's the reason because you're getting freeze, you're doing everything at the same time.

Please, look:

- [Threads Tutorial](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial)
- [Thread Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531938/java-thread-example)

Comment: not incorrect, but not the whole story either: all swing-view-related access must happen on a particular thread, the ominous EDT :-)

Answer (score 1):

A thread can only do one thing at a time. So if you let it do calculations it will not update the gui. So you should use another thread. Also you will probably need to repaint your gui.

Comment: If you use another thread to read files you don't need to repaint manually as this is normally done by the EDT.

Comment: Ah cool. Wasn't sure. I have had problems with repainting in the past, so I thought I'd just mention it.