# Creating multiple threads by extending thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to know how multiple threads can be created by "extending the Thread class". I know how it is done using "Runnable". Please tell me how it can be done by "extending Thread class".

Comment: Why dont you show us what you have tried and then we can help you out.

Comment: I'm a beginner to java. I don't know how its done. I'm having problems getting started

Comment: Here you go : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: example on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2531984/1554314

Comment: You don't want to do it by extending Thread. Runnable is better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread?rq=1

Comment: If you do some homework and then ask. It will be more useful for you and easier for people to explain.

Comment: @user2798783 posted the reference + code for initial help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Main Method**

```
public class ThreadDemo 
{   

  public static void main(String args[])    
  {         

    //Creating an object of the first thread        
    FirstThread   firstThread = new FirstThread();              

    //Creating an object of the Second thread       
    SecondThread   secondThread = new SecondThread();               

    //Starting the first thread         
    firstThread.start();                

    //Starting the second thread        
    secondThread.start();   
  } 
}
```

> This class is made as a thread by extending "Thread" class.

```
public class FirstThread extends Thread 
{ 
  //This method will be executed when this thread is executed 
  public void run() 
  { 

    //Looping from 1 to 10 to display numbers from 1 to 10 
     for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) 
     { 
        //Displaying the numbers from this thread 
        System.out.println( "Messag from First Thread : " +i); 

        /*taking a delay of one second before displaying next number 
        * 
        * "Thread.sleep(1000);" - when this  statement is executed, 
        * this thread will sleep for 1000  milliseconds (1 second) 
        * before executing the next statement. 
        * 
        * Since  we are making this thread to sleep for one second, 
        * we need to handle  "InterruptedException". Our thread 
        * may throw this exception if it is  interrupted while it 
        * is sleeping. 
        * 
        */
        try
        { 
           Thread.sleep(1000); 
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException  interruptedException) 
        { 
          /*Interrupted exception will be thrown when a sleeping or  waiting 
          * thread is interrupted. 
          */
          System.out.println(  "First Thread is interrupted when it is  sleeping" +interruptedException); 
        } 
      } 
   }
```

> This class is made as a thread by extending "Thread" class.

```
public class SecondThread extends Thread 
{   

  //This method will be executed when this thread is executed   
  public void run()     
  {             
    //Looping from 1 to 10 to display numbers from 1 to 10      
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)        
    {           
       System.out.println( "Messag from Second Thread : " +i);                      
       /*taking a delay of one second before displaying next number
       * "Thread.sleep(1000);" - when this statement is executed,
       * this thread will sleep for 1000 milliseconds (1 second) 
       * before executing the next statement.             
       *              
       * Since we are making this thread to sleep for one second,
       * we need to handle "InterruptedException". Our thread
       * may throw this exception if it is interrupted while it 
       * is sleeping.             
       */          
       try         
       {                
          Thread.sleep (1000);          
       }            
       catch (InterruptedException interruptedException)            
       {                
          /*Interrupted exception will be thrown when a sleeping or waiting
           *thread is interrupted.               
           */              
           System.out.println( "Second Thread is interrupted when it is sleeping" +interruptedException);           
       }        
    }   
  }
}
```

Please check Reference # [Threading using Extend](http://www.careerbless.com/java/Threads/ExtendingThreadClass.php) for complete detail, For quick reading i m posting code from above mentioned reference