# Java Spring Batch: How to Verify That Execution is Done in Parallel?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-batch

With classic java multithreaded execution, the parallelized execution can be proved easily (see: [SO: Java Thread Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531938/java-thread-example))
by calling

```
this.getId()
```

which results in a System.output.println():

```
[ID 9]
[ID 10]
[ID 8]
```

How can I prove that parallel execution really happens in Java Spring Batch/Spring Boot?

Comment: do you use jobs in spring batch?

Comment: spring boot batch is completely new to me. So if it helps, I could use jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a very generic way would be:

```
    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.println(thread);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the [documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) describes you can configure `jobs` and `steps`.

To see which job or step is currently running you will give both a name.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class BatchConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

  @Autowired
  private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

  @Bean
  public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
          public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
            return null;
          }
        })
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Job job(Step step1) throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(step1)
        .build();
  }
}
```

And [JobExecution](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecution.html) has many information about your job.

Here some useful docs:

- [Configuring and Running a Job](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html)
- [Creating a Batch Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/)
- [Spring Batch Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-batch-tutorial/)

Comment: How can I use JobExecution from within a step?