# Java thread order of execution

Tags: java

I have this java main method as

```
public class ThreadJoinExample {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestJoinClass t1 = new TestJoinClass("t1");  
        TestJoinClass t2 = new TestJoinClass("t2");  
        TestJoinClass t3 = new TestJoinClass("t3");  
        t1.start();  
        try{  
            t1.join();  
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
        t2.start(); 
        //thread 3 won't start until thread 2 is complete
        t3.start();  
    }

}
```

My thread class is

```
public class TestJoinClass extends Thread{
    //Constructor to assign a user defined name to the thread
    public TestJoinClass(String name)
    {
        super(name);
    }
    public void run(){  
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){  
        try{
            //stop the thread for 1/2 second
            Thread.sleep(500);  
            }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+
                " i = "+i);  
        }  
     }
}
```

The output for this program is

```
t1 i = 1
t1 i = 2
t1 i = 3
t1 i = 4
t1 i = 5
t3 i = 1
t2 i = 1
t3 i = 2
t2 i = 2
t3 i = 3
t2 i = 3
t3 i = 4
t2 i = 4
t3 i = 5
t2 i = 5
```

I have just a minor question. I was wondering why does t3 start running first instead of t2? In the code, it shows that t2.start() executes first before t3.start(). Shouldn't the output show that t2 executes first before t3 as well? Thank you

Comment: *//thread 3 won't start until thread 2 is complete* **is incorrect**

Comment: t2 t3 will run parallel, so result will random

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Thread Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531938/java-thread-example)

Comment: Threads t2 and t3 are asynchrounous threads.It is not possible to determine who finished first.

Comment: `t2.start()` is called from the main thread.  However, this does not mean the program immediately switches from the main thread to `t2`.  (Maybe it does, maybe it doesn't, you can't tell.)  In this case, the main thread keeps executing and now calls `t3.start()`.  When the JVM finally decides to stop the main thread and give another thread a chance to run, both `t2` and `t3` are available, so it picks one--no telling which.

Comment: The moral is that when using threads, if you want things to happen in a certain order, you'll need to add your own synchronization code so that all your threads can coordinate their activities.

Answer (score 1):

This demonstrates a common bug in many peoples understanding of concurrency in Java.

Your `bug` is here:

```
//thread 3 won't start until thread 2 is complete
```

it should read

```
//thread 2 and 3 will run in parallel, may start in any order and may also interleave their output
```

Answer (score 0):

When a java thread's object calls its start() method the program gets prepared to execute the run() method in a separate thread and the original calling thread continues to execute. So, as soon as **t2.start();** is called, **t2** thread prepares to execute codes of its run method.

But it is not guaranteed that first line of code in **t2**'s run() will be executed first before executing first line of code of t3's run() although **t2.start()** is called before **t3.start()** in code. So you may get different execution order & output for t2 & t3 for the current code on different machine / different run etc.

So, summary is it's totally up to the VM to choose which line of code between two of the parallel executing run() method gets executed first.