# Understanding of Asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

From this [medium article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-from-callbacks-to-async-await-1cc090ddad99), it says

> This is an example of a synchronous code:
>
> console.log('1')
>
> console.log('2')
>
> console.log('3')
>
> This code will reliably log “1 2 3".
>
> Asynchronous requests will wait for a timer to finish or a request to respond while the rest of the code continues to execute. Then when the time is right a callback will spring these asynchronous requests into action.

```
console.log('1')
setTimeout(function afterTwoSeconds() {
  console.log('2')
}, 2000)
console.log('3')

//prints 1 3 2
```

And I came across `Async/Await` by using below code

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('2');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('1');
  var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
  console.log('3');
}
asyncCall();
```

Not sure if I understand wrongly but seems to me that keyword `async` and `await` turns a `Asynchronous` function into a `synchronous` function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Await/Async Feature - What if you do not have the await word in the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911869/javascript-await-async-feature-what-if-you-do-not-have-the-await-word-in-the-f) The first answer should satisfy your question.

Comment: NOTHING turns an asynchronous function into a synchronous one - just a moments thought about it, and you'd understand why - i.e. if something takes an unknown amount of time, how can the amount of time it takes be known

Comment: Put a `console.log(4)` after your line with `asyncCall()`.

Comment: Truthfully it does not make them synchronous; it only makes the code useable in a syntactic style that is like synchronous code.

Comment: Your `asyncCall` function can also be written like `var asyncCall = _ => (console.log(1), resolveAfter2Seconds()).then(console.log).then( _ => console.log(3));`. It's totally asynchronous.